# ajax request, but refresh the whole page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When ajax request gets 401 response, I show login **modal**.

When ajax request gets 200 response, I want to load the response html.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
      401: function(){
        //do something
      });
    }
 });

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    context: document.body,
    success: function(response) {
      $(this).html(response);
    }
  });
```

But it doesn't update the url, and actually it has some problem with requirejs which I cannot describe succinctly (it spits error `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'require' of object [object Object] is not a function`)

The question is, how do I simulate the regular request/response when the request is actually made via ajax?

Comment: can you please upload your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make an "ajax request which refreshes the whole page" and updates the address bar, *don't*.

Just reload the whole page: `window.location.href = url;`

If your AJAX request returns a 401, trying to replace the entire page content with a login form is backwards. Just redirect the browser to the login form.

Comment: so that means, I better do an ajax request to see if server responded with 401 (to show login modal) and do another trip with `window.location.href=url` ? You see I was wondering if it's possible to do it in one trip.

Comment: Is it a modal, or a page? They're not the same thing. If you want to show a login modal over top of your existing page, that is a **very** different question. Also, trying to use AJAX to preserve HTTP requests this way isn't a worth-while goal. There is absolutely nothing wrong with performing a full-page reload.

Comment: sorry it's a modal I meant.